# Bootstrap Validation for horizontal form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am facing a weird issue with the Bootstrap Validator that I am using. Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p6jytvLj/
**Note**: Resize the output window to see the actual form.

**HTML Code**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="main-form" role="form" method="post">
   <!-- Text input-->
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="inputProjectID">Project ID </label>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-3-input">
         <input id="inputProjectID" name="inputProjectID" type="text" placeholder="Your Project ID" class="form-control input-md">
      </div>
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="inputProjectName">Project Name </label>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-3-input">
         <input id="inputProjectName" name="inputProjectName" type="text"
            placeholder="Your Project Name" class="form-control input-md">
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- Text input-->
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="datepicker">Release Date </label>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-3-input">
         <input id="datepicker" name="inputReleaseDate" type="text"
            placeholder="Select Release Date" class="form-control input-md">
      </div>
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="inputSupervisor">Supervisor </label>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-3-input">
         <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="Your Supervisor's Name" class="form-control input-md">
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- Text area -->
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="inputProjectDesc">Project Description </label>
      <div class="col-md-9 col-9-input">
         <textarea style="resize: none;" rows="3" class="form-control" id="inputProjectDesc"
            name="inputProjectDesc" placeholder="Your Project Description"></textarea>
      </div>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" form="main-form" data-toggle="tooltip"
      title="Click to submit this form" onclick="submitForms()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#main-form').bootstrapValidator({
            framework: 'bootstrap',
            icon: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                inputProjectID: {
                    row: 'col-md-3',
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The Project ID is required'
                        }
                    }
                },
                inputProjectName: {
                    row: 'col-md-3',
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The Project Name is required'
                        }
                    }
                },
                inputReleaseDate: {

                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Please select a Release Date'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
});
```

The issue that I am facing is I have setup validation only for first 3 fields i.e. ProjectID,Project Name & Release Date. As soon as i click submit button, the bootstrap error class applies to the adjacent field Supervisor as well. Any ideas how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: add an  other class in Supervisor input field and set default border color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a way to handle multiple form-groups in a single line. Just created a div surrounding each input, assigned it a class & then mentioned the class name in the JS code. See the updated HTML & JS code below.

**HTML code**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="main-form" role="form" data-toggle="validator"
   action="blank.html" method="post">
   <!-- Text input -->
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="group"> <!-- Added this div surrounding each input -->
         <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="inputProjectID">Project ID </label>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-3-input">
            <input id="inputProjectID" name="inputProjectID" type="text" placeholder="Your Project ID"
               class="form-control input-md">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
         <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="inputProjectName">Project Name </label>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-3-input">
            <input id="inputProjectName" name="inputProjectName" type="text"
               placeholder="Your Project Name" class="form-control input-md">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- Text input -->
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="group">
         <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="datepicker">Release Date </label>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-3-input">
            <input id="datepicker" name="inputReleaseDate" type="text"
               placeholder="Select Release Date" class="form-control input-md">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
         <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="inputSupervisor">Supervisor </label>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-3-input">
            <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="Your Supervisor's Name"
               class="form-control input-md">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- Text area -->
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="inputProjectDesc">Project Description </label>
      <div class="col-md-9 col-9-input">
         <textarea style="resize: none;" rows="3" class="form-control" id="inputProjectDesc"
            name="inputProjectDesc" placeholder="Your Project Description"></textarea>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

**JS Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#main-form').bootstrapValidator({
                framework : 'bootstrap',
                feedbackIcons : {
                    valid : 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                    invalid : 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                    validating : 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                },
                fields : {
                    inputProjectID : {
                        group : '.group',
                        validators : {
                            notEmpty : {
                                message : 'The Project ID is required'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    inputProjectName : {
                        group : '.group',
                        validators : {
                            notEmpty : {
                                message : 'The Project Name is required'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    inputReleaseDate : {
                        group : '.group',
                        validators : {
                            notEmpty : {
                                message : 'Please select a Release Date'
                            },
                            date : {
                                format : 'MM/DD/YYYY'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

This finally worked for me!!
Here's the updated Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/p6jytvLj/7/

Comment: It's work for me, This help me solved the problems.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it seems on validation error entire `form-group` is applied with validation error.

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/p6jytvLj/2/

`control-label` class was causing this issue. I have removed it from  `Supervisor` and now it works as expected.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="main-form" role="form" method="post">
    <!-- Text input -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="inputProjectID">Project ID </label>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-3-input">
            <input id="inputProjectID" name="inputProjectID" type="text"
                placeholder="Your Project ID" class="form-control input-md" />
        </div>
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="inputProjectName">Project Name </label>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-3-input">
            <input id="inputProjectName" name="inputProjectName" type="text"
                placeholder="Your Project Name" class="form-control input-md" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Text input -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="datepicker">Release Date </label>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-3-input">
            <input id="datepicker" name="inputReleaseDate" type="text"
                placeholder="Select Release Date" class="form-control input-md" />
        </div>
        <label class="col-md-2" for="inputSupervisor">Supervisor </label>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-3-input">
            <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text"
                placeholder="Your Supervisor's Name" class="form-control input-md" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Text area -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="inputProjectDesc">Project Description
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-9-input">
            <textarea style="resize: none;" rows="3" class="form-control"
                id="inputProjectDesc" name="inputProjectDesc" placeholder="Your Project Description"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" form="main-form"
        data-toggle="tooltip" title="Click to submit this form" onclick="submitForms()">Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: I have tried out this. It doesn't work. Also i want the fields adjacent to each other hence both of them are in a single form-group instead of individual one.

Comment: I want the supervisor field to be adjacent with Release date field. That's my requirement. Else this might have been one solution

Comment: @JestinoSam i fixed it. Please check the updated answer and fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/p6jytvLj/2/

Comment: I can see the error class still getting applied to Supervisor field in your fiddle. Not working as expected.

Comment: @JestinoSam hve u cheked updated fiddle in answer? /2 link?

Comment: @AnamShah Check my updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/p6jytvLj/7/  This is what I was expecting. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Only one mistake. Replace your HTML with mine
Mistake is : you missed the form group class for supervisior.

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" id="main-form" role="form" method="post">
  <!-- Text input-->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="inputProjectID">Project ID </label>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-3-input">
      <input id="inputProjectID" name="inputProjectID" type="text" placeholder="Your Project ID"
             class="form-control input-md">
    </div>
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="inputProjectName">Project Name </label>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-3-input">
      <input id="inputProjectName" name="inputProjectName" type="text"
             placeholder="Your Project Name" class="form-control input-md">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Text input-->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="datepicker">Release Date </label>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-3-input">
      <input id="datepicker" name="inputReleaseDate" type="text"
             placeholder="Select Release Date" class="form-control input-md">
    </div>  

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="inputSupervisor">Supervisor </label>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-3-input">
      <input id="inputSupervisor" name="inputSupervisor" type="text" placeholder="Your Supervisor's Name"
             class="form-control input-md">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Text area -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="inputProjectDesc">Project Description </label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-9-input">
      <textarea style="resize: none;" rows="3" class="form-control" id="inputProjectDesc"
                name="inputProjectDesc" placeholder="Your Project Description"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" form="main-form" data-toggle="tooltip"
          title="Click to submit this form" onclick="submitForms()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Updated Fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/anam8431/psrdzk2m/1/

Comment: Sorry this is not what I am expecting. Please have a look to the fiddle clearly.

Comment: May i know what are you expecting?

Comment: Check the fiddle. I have applied validations only to Project ID, Project Name & Release date but still the error class is getting applied to Supervisor field as well. Seems the whole form-group is getting selected

Comment: Hey Jestino, please check my fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/anam8431/psrdzk2m/1/. The Supervisor field is not going to be validated at the time of validate the form.

Comment: I have clearly mentioned that I need supervisor field next to release-date. Please read the above comments